# How to save values selected in Spinner so that values do not change while sliding through ViewPager

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using "ViewPager" to slide through pages and I am using Spinner component in all pages, now while sliding, i am loosing the values I selected in previous page, how to save the state of spinner component, so that even after sliding through pages, the values do not change. Below is my code :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterClass.this);

// Spinner Drop down elements
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
categories.add("Automobile");
categories.add("Business Services");
categories.add("Computers");
categories.add("Education");
categories.add("Personal");
categories.add("Travel");

// Creating adapter for spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

// Drop down layout style - list view with radio button           
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// attaching data adapter to spinner
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Sounds good, do you have example @KaveeshKanwal?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and do something like this:

```
int spinnerPosition = yourSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Store it in shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = yourContext.getSharedPreferences("spinnerPositionValue", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("spinnerPositiionValueKey", spinnerPosition);
        editor.commit();
```

Now, wherever in your activity or fragment wherever you are losing the value of your spinner just check your shared preference for the value, get the value and update your spinner item.

```
int savedSpinnerPosition = sharedPref.getInt("spinnerPositiionValueKey");
yourSpinner.setSelection(savedSpinnerPosition);
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here was the easiest way to do it. If you are using ViewPager, then save your state by using below line

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(300);
```

Make the value very high (say 300). It will save state upto 300 pages

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); // the number of "off screen" pages to keep loaded each side of the current page
pager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(context));
```